# C++ | Trying to create a "Modify" option in C++ doesn't work

Tags: c++, file, logic, fstream

I'm working in a little project about a Coffe Shop. I'm trying to develope an option to modify any item in the "ListaDeProductos.dat" file, which store all the items created by the user. I found a very old code I made it 4 years ago, lol, and there is some chunks of code I don't know how it works (If anyone can explain me how it works, I will be so greatfull). The thing is I need help to see what's going wrong with the code and why the modified data doesn't storage correctly.

To do this modification, I did that:

- Open "ListaDeProductos.dat"
- Open "ProductosAux.dat", this file is a copy of the first file, but this one store the modified content
- Ask for the ID of the item is going to be modified
- Check if "ListaDeProductos.dat"  exist
- If exist, the system check, item by item if the ID exist, if yes, the system would ask for the new data, if no, "ProductosAux.dat" is removed
- use the following code that I don't remember exactlely what  do:

  fseek(ProductosAuxiliar,0l,SEEK_END);
              fread(&nuevoproducto,sizeof(Producto),1,Productos);
              fwrite(&nuevoproducto,sizeof(Producto),1,ProductosAuxiliar);
- Close both files
- If changes are made, the system ask if you want to save it
- If yes, "ListaDeProductos.dat" is removed and "ProductosAux.dat" is renamed to "ListaDeProductos.dat"
- If no, "ProductosAux.dat" is removed

Here is the code  who matters for this operation:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h> 
#include <string>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main (void)
{
    typedef struct{
    int codigo;
    char N_Produc [20];// N_Product = Name of item
    char ID_Produc [20];//ID_Produc = ID of Product
    char Precio_Product[20]; // Price of the Item
}Producto;

char N_Produc[20];
char Precio_Product[20];
char ID_Produc[20];
Productos = fopen ("ListaDeProductos.dat", "r+");// abre el archivo en modod de adicion "r+": Escritura y Lectura por medio de modificacion.
cout << "================================================================================" << endl
     << "               Welcome to Modify" << endl
     << "================================================================================" << endl << endl;

    FILE *Productos;
    FILE *ProductosAuxiliar; 
    Producto nuevoproducto;
    int codigoaux;
    bool registro=false;
    int opcionmodificar=0, opcionguardar=0;
    Productos = fopen("ListaDeProductos.dat","r");
    ProductosAuxiliar = fopen("ProductosAux.dat","a+");
    printf("Insert ID: ");
    scanf("%d",&codigoaux);
    getchar();
    if(Productos!=NULL)
    {
    fread(&nuevoproducto,sizeof(Producto),1,Productos);
        while (!feof(Productos))
            {
                if (nuevoproducto.codigo == codigoaux)
                {
                    printf("\nCodigo: %d \nNombre: %s \nPrecio: %s\n\n",nuevoproducto.codigo, nuevoproducto.N_Produc, nuevoproducto.Precio_Product);

                    cout<<"Are you sure to Modify? <y/n>";
                    scanf("%s", &opcionmodificar);
                    getchar();
                    if(opcionmodificar=='y'||opcionmodificar=='Y')
                    {
//                  printf("     Insert Name: ");
//                  scanf("%d",&prove.codigo);
                        cout<<"\n     Nombre Producto: ";
                        scanf("%s",nuevoproducto.N_Produc);
                         cout<<"\n     Price: ";
                        scanf("%s",nuevoproducto.Precio_Product);
                        registro=true;
                    }
                }
            fseek(ProductosAuxiliar,0l,SEEK_END);
            fread(&nuevoproducto,sizeof(Producto),1,Productos);
            fwrite(&nuevoproducto,sizeof(Producto),1,ProductosAuxiliar);
        }
    }
    fclose(Productos);
    fclose(ProductosAuxiliar);

    if(registro==true)
    {
        printf("\n Want to keep it? <y/n>");
        scanf("%s",&opcionguardar);
        if(opcionguardar=='y'||opcionguardar=='Y')
        {
           remove("ListaDeProductos.dat");
           rename("ProductosAux.dat","ListaDeProductos.dat");
           cout<<"\nData modified \n";
        }
        else
        {
            remove("ProductosAux.dat");
            cout<<"Data not modified\n";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        remove("ProductosAux.dat");
        cout<<"Entry not found\n";
    }
   system("PAUSE()");

   cout << "Want to modify another? <y/n> ";
   regreso = getch();
}while (regreso == 'y'|| regreso =='Y');
     remove("ProductosAux.dat");
```

The Output is the same data before I try to modify it. 
[This is on the code working, at the top is the data inside "ListaDeProductos.dat" and down is the form to update the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftrLI.png)

Please,check that the Running code is in Spanish, I adapted it to everyone the best possible, so i wish you can understand it.

Comment: If it's easier for you to communicate in Spanish, note that there is [Stack Overflow in Spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com/). But I really think your question needs a [mcve].

Comment: I didn't know Stack Overflow haves a Spanish version. Thanks! And it's very posible that the answer is simpliest that I think. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Don't focus too heavily on minimal. Minimal is nice, but in the end it is useless if the given example does not provide enough or complete enough information to allow us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Tried to format the code so it would be a bit easier to read, but it looks like the indentation is broken. It's really hard to tell someone where their code is broken if turning it into a question broke it further.

Comment: Side note: It looks like you're learning C rather than C++. Other than a couple `cout`s, the code is written using C functions and idioms. C's a great language and it inter-operates with C++ reasonably well, but at the end of the day it's a different language and should be learned separately.